# Creating ALB trigger for Lambda using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ansible, aws-sdk, aws-cli

Form the AWS management console, ALB can be used as trigger for Lambda function.

[image: ALB as Trigger]

However, I cannot find the same thing using AWS CLI.

[LINK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-event-source-mapping.html)

In CLI, only Kinesis, SQS and DynamoDB options are available.

So, am I checking the wrong documentation or there is way to create ALB trigger for Lambda function using CLI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think of it the other way around. Instead of adding a trigger to the Lambda function, you need to **point the Load Balancer to the Lambda function**.

This can be done via:

```
aws elbv2 create-target-group --target-type lambda ...
```

Comment: `aws s3api put-bucket-notification-configuration --notification-configuration {... LambdaFunctionConfigurations...}`